# Looking for finite difference approximations past the fourth derivative

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

[I scanned the internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-point_stencil) and could not find further representations of the central difference approximations past the fourth derivative. Are there published results past the fourth derivative?

Ideally I am looking to find up to the $12$th derivative. It doesn't sound like an enjoyable exercise by pencil and paper. Is this information known?

Central difference approximations up to the $4$th derivative:

$f'(x)\approx\dfrac{-f(x+2h)+8f(x+h)-8f(x-h)+f(x-2h)}{12h}$

$f''(x)\approx\dfrac{-f(x+2h)+16f(x+h)-30f(x)+16f(x-h)-f(x-2h)}{12h^2}$

$f^{(3)}(x)\approx\dfrac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+2f(x-h)-f(x-2h)}{2h^3}$

$f^{(4)}(x)\approx\dfrac{f(x+2h)-4f(x+h)+6f(x)-4f(x-h)+f(x-2h)}{h^4}$

Comment: Hmm... those coefficients look interesting.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient could be of interest to you.

Comment: A finite difference formula for the 12th derivative will extremely suffer from digit cancellation. In fact I suppose that even for $f(x) = \sin x$ it will give nonzero results only when $h > 0.1$
The formula you're looking is
$$
f^{(12)}(x) \approx \frac{1}{h^{12}} \sum_{k=-6}^6 \begin{pmatrix}12\\6+k\end{pmatrix} (-1)^k f(x+kh)
$$

Comment: The accepted answer only gives even orders. Arbitrary orders are right here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For even orders the finite-difference derivative approximation has a simple form.

Consider following finite-difference operator $\Delta$
$$
\Delta f(x) = \frac{f(x+h/2) - f(x-h/2)}{h}.
$$
It's a second order first derivative operator. You can apply it several times
$$
\Delta^2 f(x) = \Delta \Delta f(x) = \Delta \left(\frac{f(x+h/2) - f(x-h/2)}{h}\right) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h^2} - \frac{f(x) - f(x-h)}{h^2}= \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2} \sim f''(x).
$$
Note that $\Delta$ can be written using shift operator $T_a = \exp\left(a \frac{d}{dx}\right)$
$$
\Delta = \frac{T_{h/2} - T_{-h/2}}{h} = \frac{e^{\frac{h}{2}\frac{d}{dx}} - e^{-\frac{h}{2}\frac{d}{dx}}}{h}.
$$
Thus powers of $\Delta$ can be easily expressed using binomial theorem (note that $T_a$ and $T_b$ commute)
$$
\Delta^{2k} = \frac{1}{h^{2k}}\sum_{m=0}^{2k} \begin{pmatrix}2k\\m\end{pmatrix} T_{h/2}^{2k-m} (-1)^m T_{-h/2}^{m} =
\frac{1}{h^{2k}}\sum_{m=0}^{2k} \begin{pmatrix}2k\\m\end{pmatrix} (-1)^m T_{(2k-m)h/2} T_{-mh/2} = \\
=\frac{1}{h^{2k}}\sum_{m=0}^{2k} \begin{pmatrix}2k\\m\end{pmatrix} (-1)^m T_{(k-m)h} = \frac{1}{h^{2k}} \sum_{m=-k}^k \begin{pmatrix}2k\\k+m\end{pmatrix} (-1)^{m+k} T_{mh}.
$$
Thus 
$$
\Delta^{2k} f(x) = \frac{1}{h^{2k}} \sum_{m=-k}^{k} \begin{pmatrix}2k\\k+m\end{pmatrix} (-1)^{m+k} f(x + mh).
$$
This will be a second order formula, since it represents $2k$ times applying second order formula to $f(x)$. Actually, the truncation error is
$$
\Delta^{2k} f(x) - f^{(2k)}(x) = \frac{kh^2}{12} f^{(2k+2)}(x) + O(h^4).
$$

But from practical point of view, the formulas for high order derivatives (maybe more than 4) are almost never used.
Let $f(x)$ be evaluated on a machine with limited number of binary digits. Let's assume double precision, which has $53$ bits of mantissa.
Thus every $f(x)$ value would have also small error $f(x) \pm \epsilon |f(x)|$ with $\varepsilon =2^{-53} \approx 10^{-16}$. Applying $\Delta^{2k}$ to this function will yield
$$
\Delta^{2k} (f(x) + \delta f(x)) = \Delta^{2k} f(x) + \Delta^{2k} \delta f(x) = f^{(2k)}(x) + \epsilon_{\text{trunc}} + \Delta^{2k} \delta f(x).
$$
For the $\delta f$ it is known that $|\delta f(x)| \leq \varepsilon |f(x)|$, but the sign can be arbitrary. Thus the best we can write for $\Delta^{2k} \delta f(x)$ is
$$
\left|\Delta^{2k} \delta f(x)\right| \leq \frac{1}{h^{2k}} \sum_{m=-k}^{k} \begin{pmatrix}2k\\k+m\end{pmatrix} |(-1)^{m+k}| \cdot |\delta f(x + mh)| \leq \frac{\epsilon \max |f(x)|}{h^{2k}} \sum_{m=-k}^{k} \begin{pmatrix}2k\\k+m\end{pmatrix} = \\ = 2^{2k}\frac{\varepsilon \max |f(x)|}{h^{2k}}.
$$
Note that the bound is tight, it's not hard to construct such $\delta f(x)$.
Since $\epsilon_{\text{trunc}} \leq \frac{kh^2}{12}\max |f^{(2k+2)|}(x)$
the total error consists of two terms
$$
\epsilon \leq \frac{kh^2}{12} M_{2k+2} + 2^{2k}\frac{\varepsilon M_0}{h^{2k}}.
$$
Here for simplicity $M_k = \max |f^(k)(x)|$. From this estimate one can find the optimal $h_\star$ and minimal achievable $\epsilon_\star$:
$$
0 = \frac{d\epsilon}{dh} = \frac{kh}{6}M_{2k+2} - 2^{2k+1}k \frac{\varepsilon M_0}{h^{2k+1}}\\
h_\star^{2k+2} = \frac{3\varepsilon 2^{2k+2}M_0}{M_{2k+2}}, \qquad
h_\star = 2 \sqrt[2k+2]\frac{3\varepsilon M_0}{M_{2k+2}}\\
\epsilon_\star = \frac{kh_\star ^2}{12} M_{2k+2} \left(
1 + 2^{2k+2}\frac{\varepsilon M_0}{h_\star^{2k+2}}\frac{3}{k M_{2k+2}}
\right) = \frac{kh_\star ^2}{12} M_{2k+2} \frac{k+1}{k}
= \frac{(k+1)h_\star ^2}{12} M_{2k+2}
$$
Here's a table for different $k$ and $M_0 = M_{2k+2} = 1$ ($f(x) = \sin x$ for example), $\varepsilon = 2^{-53}$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & h_\star & \epsilon_\star\\
\hline
 1 & 2.70186\times 10^{-4} & 1.21667\times 10^{-8} \\
 2 & 5.26565\times 10^{-3} & 6.93176\times 10^{-6} \\
 3 & 2.32459\times 10^{-2} & 1.80124\times 10^{-4} \\
 4 & 5.66609\times 10^{-2} & 1.33769\times 10^{-3} \\
 5 & 1.02622\times 10^{-1} & 5.26565\times 10^{-3} \\
 6 & 1.56854\times 10^{-1} & 1.43519\times 10^{-2} \\
 7 & 2.1562\times 10^{-1} & 3.09945\times 10^{-2} \\
 8 & 2.76166\times 10^{-1} & 5.72009\times 10^{-2} \\
 9 & 3.36633\times 10^{-1} & 9.44348\times 10^{-2} \\
 10 & 3.9583\times 10^{-1} & 1.43625\times 10^{-1} \\
\end{array}
$$
Here's also results from numerical experiments with $k=2$ (fourth order) and $k=6$ (12th order)
[image]
[image]

Note that 12th order formula hardly gave two significant digits of the derivative, while 4th order gave 6. Optimal values agree with theoretical values pretty well. To get at least 5 right digits for the 12th derivative you need double-double (128 bytes) floating point arithmetic.

Note that if you need such finite difference for some ODE, for example
$$
y^{(12)}(x) + a y^{(6)}(x) + b y'(x) + c y(x) = f(x)
$$
you can always rewrite it as a system of the first order with 12 unknows
$$
y_{11}'(x) + a y_6(x) + b y_1(x) + c y_0(x) = f(x)\\
y_{10}'(x) = y_{11}(x)\\
\vdots\\
y_{0}'(x) = y_1(x).
$$

Comment: Thank You. This directly answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I've found on the topic

[Notes on the derivation of Finite Differences kernels, on regularly spaced grids, using arbitrary sample points](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~dfeder/535/FDnotes.pdf)

Some tables on Finite differences can be found [here on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient)

There is a paper that discusses the generation of the co-efficients used

[Generation of Finite Difference Formulas on Arbitrarily Spaced Grids](http://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/fornberg/Docs/MathComp_88_FD_formulas.pdf)

The interesting thing about this paper is that the gird can be arbitrarily spaced. Note that this paper presents an algorithm for computing the co-efficients.

I've found this

$\delta^n_h[f](x)=\Sigma_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^iC_i^nf(x+(\frac{n}{2} -i)h)$

on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) although I'm still searching for a derivation.